# Turbolinks 5 replacement or bare jquery partial replacement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using Turbolink 5 beta4. When developing my app I noticed that Turbolinks is much slower than if I would replace appropriate partial with jquery myself. Here is my Turbolinks visit code:

```html
Turbolinks.visit('/courses/'+course_id, {action: 'replace'} );
```

And my bare jquery:

```html
$.ajax({
  url: '/courses/course/'+course_id,
  success: function(data){
    course_instance.html(data);
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err){
    console.error(this.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
```

So as you can see here I replace what I need myself. This way it works about 10 times faster (60ms vs ~700ms). So I am wondering how make Turbolinks this fast. I tried to add data-turbolinks-permanent to divs that I need not to change, but it seems it dint't improved speed. Can it be that because of caching Turbolinks is slower?